# Test on IOS: System.ArugumentException

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.uitest

I would like to test an IOS application on Xamarin, using XamarinUITest.
Unfortunatly, i'm not able to launch anything on my local device. 
I've succed on running test on Android but IOS seems to be a brand new mystery.

Actually i've an error that I'm not able to find any solution.
The system says :

```
System.ArgumentException : Must supply files for hashing
Parameter name: fileInfos
```

This is my code for launching the application :

```
app = ConfigureApp.IOS.Debug()
.EnableLocalScreenshots()
.DeviceIdentifier(PHYSICAL_DEVICE_ID)
.AppBundle(PATH_TO_MY_IPA)
.StartApp();
```

I've not the hand on the application, i've only an IPA that includes calabash.

Answer (score 2):

> i've only an IPA that includes calabash.

`AppBundle` requires access to the `.app`, not the `.ipa`.

Install the `.ipa` and use `InstalledApp` passing the application bundle id

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The next step is to run tests on the XTC, i won't be able to install it first right ?

Comment: Submitting UITests for an External Mobile App : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/working-with/submitting-tests-to-xamarin-test-cloud/#Submitting_UITests_for_an_External_Mobile_App